# How do I show a different homepage to logged in and non-logged in users?

Tags: plugins, registered, logging

Basically, I want to show non-logged in users a page that says 'register or log in.' But I want to show logged in users a standard homepage will all my posts.

Comment: Try this new plugin recently released https://wordpress.org/plugins/dual-homepage/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rarst's solution is indeed the simplest way to do it and the Members plugin also has heaps of other advantages.

You can also do it without a plugin, by using the is_user_logged_in() function

More info on http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo#Parameters

Answer (score 2):

Home page only or whole site?.. I assume latter as it makes more sense.

The simplest way I know is to use [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin and enable *Private Blog* option it has.

Answer (score 2):

If you're comfortable adding functions, this does the trick.

```
    /**
     * If a user is logged in, tell WordPress to use 'page' on front page of the site
     * @param string $value
     * @return string
     */
    function fn_set_page_as_front_for_loggedin_user( $value ) {
        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $value = 'page';
            //page is set as front page
        }
        return $value;
    }
    add_filter( 'pre_option_show_on_front', 'fn_set_page_as_front_for_loggedin_user' );

    /**
     * If user is not logged in, set our static page to act as home page
     * @param $value
     * @return int
     */
    function fn_set_context_based_page_on_front( $value ) {

        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return $value;
        }

        //for logged in user, use page id - in this case 56
        return 56;
        //change with your own page id.
    }
  add_filter( 'pre_option_page_on_front', 'fn_set_context_based_page_on_front' );
```

Comment: Incorrect logic on the if condition for fn_set_context_based_page_on_front. Should only return $value if user is logged in. Else give the static pageid for the login page. I had to change if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) to if( is_user_logged_in() )

Comment: Also, not sure why fn_set_page_as_front_for_loggedin_user() is needed. I was able to get this to work for the use case above just by using fn_set_context_based_page_on_front() only

Comment: Apologies for the slow response. It's been a while since I looked at this, but I'm pretty sure you need both, to avoid interference from the user settings within the dashboard. You have to accept that, once set this way, you lose any control over the start page from within the dashboard.